# A simple cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

"I do wish you'd learn to text, Auntie, or at least get email," said Nora.  She sighed and toyed with her phone as her aunt peered at her over the top of her newspaper.

"I don't see why dear," said Daphne.  "Why, only yesterday I was asking Artie what game he'd been playing at his club and what the outcome was, and look!  He's put the answer in the crossword for me."  Nora's jaw dropped in astonishment, and Daphne smiled a sweet-old-lady smile.  "But I'll tell you what," she continued, the smile widening into a crocodile-grin.  "If you can tell me what the game was and the result, I'll get a mobile phone."

Can you help Nora out, and determine the game and the outcome?

[image: Grid]

*Clues:*

**ACROSS**

2.This duo(3)

6.Writing Alice starts after school is indistinct, non-consonant(5)

8.Apply colour: nearly half a litre covers area(5)

9.Fibre obtained from thistles(5)

10.Old German politician orders man on ship(4)

**DOWN**

1.Meat jelly(snake) on mice insides(5)

3.The least bit -- woman and husband are getting some(4)

4.Possess topless dress...(3)

5....meats Gaga brings together(5)

7.Maybe Johnny brought back hospital bag(4)

Comment: 8A is only nearly half a litre in the USA. In other places it is rather more.

Comment: @RupertMorrish - that's a good point!  I'd intended to write "color" to clue the Americanism but my fingers clearly reverted to "colour" and I missed it when checking.  Now though I think that might be too subtle and I should have written "over" instead of "nearly"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ACROSS

2.This duo(3)

> TWO (ddef)

6.Writing Alice starts after school is indistinct, non-consonant(5)

> SCH + W.A.

8.Apply colour: nearly half a litre covers area(5)

> P(A)INT

9.Fibre obtained from thistles(5)

> _ISTLE_

10.Old German politician orders man on ship(4)

> HE + S.S.

DOWN

1.Meat jelly(snake) on mice insides(5)

> ASP + _IC_

3.The least bit -- woman and husband are getting some(4)

> W + H + IT

4.Possess topless dress...(3)

> (-g)OWN

5....meats Gaga brings together(5)

> MATES*

7.Maybe Johnny brought back hospital bag(4)

> (CAS + H)<

This makes the final grid:

> `ATWOM`
>  `SCHWA`
>  `PAINT`
>  `ISTLE`
>  `CHESS`

and we can see in it

> the word **CHESS** in the bottom row, and the words **WHITE MATES** reading down columns 3 and 5.

Comment: Perfect!  I'd intended the full answer to be "WHITE MATES IN TWO" but I'll happily accept this as I didn't manage to get IN TWO together in the grid.

Answer (score 4):

Clues:

ACROSS

2.This duo(3)

> TWO (ddef)

6.Writing Alice starts after school is indistinct, non-consonant(5)

> VOWEL(I don't get the wordplay.)

8.Apply colour: nearly half a litre covers area(5)

> PAINT( A in PINT)

9.Fibre obtained from thistles(5)

> ISTLE.

10.Old German politician orders man on ship(4)

DOWN

1.Meat jelly(snake) on mice insides(5)

> ASPIC (ASP+IC)

3.The least bit -- woman and husband are getting some(4)

> WHIT (W+H+IT)

4.Possess topless dress...(3)

> OWN (-(g)OWN)

5....meats Gaga brings together(5)

> Probably MATES(Meats)*

7.Maybe Johnny brought back hospital bag(4)

> CASH?

Yet, there is something wrong because the grid doesn't match up completely.

Comment: VOWEL is wrong but everything else is right (you've given no answer for 10A -- I'm guessing you just missed writing it).  Deusovi's given the wordplay above for it so I'll leave this comment as is.